# Faccing issue in detecting cardType using enum in java

Tags: java, android, regex, enums

I am developing an Android Application which accept payment. Here I am getting a problem in detecting a card type. Here I am faccing one issue in **CardType.Java Enum** return only **visa** its unable to find any other **type of card**. I am entering **600206** and my class return **visa** instead of **MAESTRO** which is wrong please help me out.

CardType.Java

```
public enum CardType {

VISA("4"),
MCRD("5"),
MAESTRO("67", "56", "502260", "504433",
        "504434", "504435", "504437", "504645", "504681",
        "504753", "504775", "504809", "504817", "504834",
        "504848", "504884", "504973", "504993", "508125",
        "508126", "508159", "508192", "508227", "600206",
        "603123", "603741", "603845", "622018"),
DINERCLUB("30", "36", "38", "39"),
JCB("35"),
AMEX("34", "37"),
DISCOVER("60", "62", "64", "65"),
UNKNOWN("0");

private final String[] pattern;

private CardType(String... pattern) {

    System.out.println("pattern== "+pattern.toString());
    this.pattern = pattern;
}




public static CardType typeOf(String card) {

    System.out.println("card== "+card);
    for (CardType type : values()) {

        System.out.println("type== "+type);
            return type;         
    }
   return null;
}

public static String getScheme(CardType cardType) {
    System.out.println("getScheme");
    switch (cardType) {
    case VISA:
        return "VISA";
    case MCRD:
        return "MCRD";
    case MAESTRO:
        return "MAESTRO";
    case DINERCLUB:
        return "DINERCLUB";
    case JCB:
        return "JCB";
    case AMEX:
        return "AMEX";
    case DISCOVER:
        return "DISCOVER";
    default:
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `typeOf` method returns the first element of the enum which is VISA, replace it with

```
public static CardType typeOf(String card) {
    for (CardType type : values()) {
        for(String numbers : type.pattern) {
            if(numbers.equals(card)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type for card pattern " + card + " was not found.");
}
```

Comment: I replaced it but it shows me an error on pattern  for(String numbers : pattern) i.e  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field pattern

Comment: hey its working fine now thanks..  if my question is valid then plz rate my question .... :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return type;
```

which would always return the first enum constant (VISA), do

```
if (Stream.of(pattern).anyMatch((p) -> card.startsWith(p))) {
    return type;
}
```

(Java 8) StartsWith assumed.

---

Java 7:

```
for (String p : pattern) { 
    if (card.startsWith(p)) {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: its shows me an error i.e.  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field pattern

Comment: `type.pattern` though pattern is private.